# How to change the color of text of TextView in android according to chosen color, selected from a list of color

Tags: android, listview, textview, onitemclicklistener

I have made a List of color and I want to change the color of text of `TextView` having id "Name of User" as soon as Someone  click on one  of the the item of the List .I tried following code but its not working .I m unable to figure out what is wrong in the following code:

```
public class UserInformation extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_information);
        Bundle app = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (app == null) {
            return;
        }
        final TextView Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NameOfUser);//refernce to textview
        Name.setText(app.getString("user_information"));

        String[] color = {"Blue", "Red", "Green"};
        ListAdapter mylist = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, color);
        ListView renuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Mylist);
        renuList.setAdapter(mylist);

        renuList.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        String item = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(i));
                        if (item == "Green") {                       
                            Name.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);// suppose I want to set the color to green if green is selected   
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
}
```

Comment: Do you know such java's basics as how to compare Strings in java?

Comment: Use ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.XXX) for colors!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

Seems like you're calling `getItemIdAtPosition()` instead of `getItemAtPosition()`.

Assuming you would like to get the data from your adapter at the given position, you should change the following:

```
String item = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(i));
```

To:

```
String item = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

**Problem 2:**

Another problem is you're comparing your (supposedly) strings with the `==` operator.

The `==` operator checks reference equality when comparing objects (`String` is an `Object`) and you need to check value equality here.

Instead of this:

```
if (item == "Green") {
```

You might want to do this:

```
if ("Green".equals(item)) {
```

From the documentation of `String.equals()`:

> `boolean equals (Object anObject)`
>
> Compares this string to the specified
>   object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and
>   is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as
>   this object.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/3363481) on `String` equality.